# how to create wordpress admin menu and link to page

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

**I want to create a plugin** i got error : **You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page**. there are 2 file 
buffer.php 
bufferpage.php

i already create admin menu but i want to display/show  "bufferpage.php" **in right side after click submenu named Submenu-3**

but notworking :(

buffer.php **is here**

```
//Register the main menu name “buffercode_menu”
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'buffercode_menu');


    //adding menu menu in wordpress admin panel
    function buffercode_menu() {

    add_menu_page( 'BufferCode plugin page', 'Menu plugin settings','manage_options', __FILE__,'buffercode_plugin',plugins_url( '/images/menu-icon.png', __FILE__ ) );

    //submenu
    add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BufferCode Submenu','Submenu-1', 'manage_options',__FILE__.'_menu1', buffercode_plugin );
    add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BufferCode Submenu','Submenu-2', 'manage_options',__FILE__.'_menu1', buffercode_plugin );
    add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BufferCode Submenu','Submenu-3', 'manage_options',__FILE__. $view_level, 'bufferpage.php' );
    }
```

here is bufferpage.php

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php echo "<h2>" . __( 'Sample page', 'buffercode_menu' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

<?php

global $wpdb;
/* wpdb class should not be called directly.global $wpdb variable is an instantiation of the class already set up to talk to the WordPress database */ 

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans "); /*mulitple row results can be pulled from the database with get_results function and outputs an object which is stored in $result */

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
/* If you require you may print and view the contents of $result object */

?>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="116" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF99"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="146" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF99"><strong>Email</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
foreach($result as $row)
 {
echo "<tr align=center>
    <td>$row->name</td>
    <td>$row->email</td>
  </tr>";
 }
 /* Print the contents of $result looping through each row returned in the result */

?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:--

```
add_menu_page( 'BufferCode plugin page', 'Menu plugin settings', 'manage_options', 'menu-plugin-settings', 'buffercode_plugin',plugins_url( '/images/menu-icon.png', __FILE__ ) );

add_submenu_page('menu-plugin-settings', 'BufferCode Submenu', 'Submenu-1', 'manage_options', 'submenu-1', 'submenu_1_page');

function submenu_1_page()
{
    include_once 'bufferpage.php';
}
```

Comment: not working 

after add this i got link like this : 

http://localhost/student/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=customplugin/index.php

Comment: Very very thank you ............. @Akshay yes it's working :)

can u tell me how to add two more sub menu ???

Comment: As same as above...
add another `add_submenu_page` and create new function for that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will help you

```
function custom_button_example($wp_admin_bar){
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'menu_id',
        'title' => 'menu name',
        'href' => 'http://exaple.com/',
        'meta' => array(
            'class' => 'custom-button-class'
        )
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_button_example', 50);
```

Comment: my problem is solve anyway thankyou for your time :)